# Where does the C wire go in my A/C - Furnace?

Tags: hvac

I know there are similar questions asked but I can't make sense of the diagram in mine. The wire was already run, and you can see the small blue wire hanging disconnected in the picture. Diagram attached. 
I'm not not sure where to connect it in the combo A/C - heat unit. 
Thanks for any help.

Unfortunately I can only post one picture...so please try to explain as you would to a child...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking where it physically connects to inside of your A/C-Furnace? Or do you need to know where it hooks to your thermostat?

Comment: If you post the other photos to [Imgur](http://imgur.com/), and post a link to them here. Somebody will be able to edit them into the question.

Comment: correct, I know where it goes in the stat, but not on the A/C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like your unit exposes the `C` wire directly, so you'll have to run your own wire from the transformer.  Not sure where the transformer is physically in your unit, but here it is on the schematic.

[image]

You'll notice a terminal on the secondary side of the transformer, with a bunch of blue wires connected to it. This is the `C` terminal, and where you'll want to connect your `C` wire.

Comment: Thank you! Here's a link to the transformer. So on the bottom right is where it needs to go correct? http://i.imgur.com/VnByUke.jpg

Comment: Wait...it should actually be the top left in this picture because the transformer is upside down.

Comment: Trace the wires out to make sure, but yes. It appears that the upper left terminal in your photo would be `C`.

Comment: Everything is up and running, new stat is working beautifully and after troubleshooting a faulty wire (the C wire of course) I'm GTG. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @HeavyMetalMonk No problem, glad to hear you got it working.